# .NET System.Diagnostics.Process output is incomplete

Tags: .net, cmd, process, output

I am unable to retrieve a complete output of a command executed in a shell. The program first writes a line stating it's connecting to a server to fetch data, then  it shows fetched data. In my tiny VB app **I always get only that first line**, which is indicating that the command is supplied with proper and verified arguments, but the rest of ouptut doesn't get through.

First, I just tried to read it with `WaitForExit()` and `ReadToEnd()`. Then reading it line by line with `oProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine()`.

As suggested in some thread, I tried to disable `WaitForExit()` and include loop that waits for a process to exit:

```
    Dim oProcess As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
    Dim oStartInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("net", " user %USERNAME% /DOMAIN")
    oStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    oStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    oStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    oProcess.StartInfo = oStartInfo
    oProcess.Start()
    'oProcess.WaitForExit()

    Dim lns As String
    Dim q As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    While Not (oProcess.HasExited)
        q.Append(oProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd())
        lns &= q.ToString()
    End While
    Me.TextBox1.Text &= lns & vbCrLf
```

I tried to include a `Thread.Sleep(500)` as suggested in another thread.

Still just one line. Obviously, it works like a charm from the CMD. Any ideas, please?

Comment: If it's the `net` command, i guess the remaining output is on stderr, not stdout. Try capture stderr too.

Comment: @Zilog80 OK, that makes sense from the point of not seeing it. Thank you for suggestion, will try.

Comment: You might want to consider using the types built into .NET for interacting with Active Directory directly rather than shelling out to a command line tool and then having to parse it's output.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, that's a possibility, though it's quite an overkill to burden a tiny little feature with an AD query. The main problem there is, that for the moment I don't have all the information I need (like what OU is called) to set LDAP part.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was rather silly, due to my little experience I didn't realized that in case of an error the error message goes into a different (error) output. That lead me to *incorrectly describe the problem.*

When reading the error output, I could see the query returns error that user is not found. The `%USERNAME%`wasn't processed and replacing it with `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME")` fixed everything.